# Gradle Spring Boot - spring jar versions are not automatically picked up

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, gradle-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am trying out a simple gradle spring boot application as per the below URL

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'my-jar'
    version =  '1.0.0'
}


dependencies {

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    testCompile "junit:junit"
}
```

I am using a local artifactory and my init.gradle has the buildscript configuration which is below

```
buildscript {
        repositories {

                maven {
                url 'http://mylocalartifactory:8081/'
                }

        }

        dependencies {  classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE" }
    }
```

I get the below error when i try to run gradlew build

```
What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:.
```

Looks like the version is not getting applied for the dependency.
What I understand is that the version will be defaulted by the spring-boot plugin .

Am I missing something ?

It works fine if I mention the version number in the dependency

```
dependencies {

    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.2.RELEASE"
    testCompile "junit:junit"
}
```

Though I can make it work , it beats the purpose of using spring boot if I need to manually specify the spring version jar dependency .

Kindly revert back if you see any issue in my build.gradle or init.gradle

Comment: Are you sure that you have such dependency in the artifactory? Have you enabled mirroring in the artifactory?

Comment: yes.  Build works fine if i mention the version number like below                      
                                                                                            
 dependencies {
    
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.2.RELEASE"
    testCompile "junit:junit"
}

Comment: Is your `buildscript` block inside an `allprojects` block?

Comment: yes buildscript is within the allprojects block in my init.gradle